# MySQL query to compare two date and it will traverse from one column to other

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have a table `pa_acc_status`, I have attached the image of table.

I want to compare 2 date (one 'll be user input and other will be column value) and it will traverse from one column to other in a loop using MYSQL.

For example: first it will check that `step_22_due_date` column is not null and `step_22_due_date` <= `USER_DATE`, if this is true then exit for that row and continue with next row otherwise do same for step_21_complete, then step_21_due_date, then step_1_complete

ie `step_22_due_date` -> `step_21_complete` -> `step_21_due_date` -> `step_1_complete`

I want the output in 2 ways

**CASE 1: for USER_DATE = `2016-09-03`**

First Like this

```
id | step_1_complete | step_21_due_date | step_21_complete | step_22_due_date | user_id
1  |      NULL       | 2016-03-12       | NULL             | NULL             | 1
2  |      NULL       | 2016-03-12       | NULL             | NULL             | 1
3  |      NULL       |      NULL        |      NULL        | 2016-04-15       | 2
4  |      NULL       | 2016-03-12       | NULL             | NULL             | 2
5  |      NULL       |      NULL        | 2016-03-12       | NULL             | 2
```

And second one which is the count of the date which is not null and `group by user_id`

```
step_1_complete | step_21_due_date | step_21_complete | step_22_due_date | user_id
0          |  2         |  0         |  0         | 1
0          |  1         |  1         |  1         | 2
```

**CASE 2: for USER_DATE = `2016-03-10`**

First Like this

```
id | step_1_complete | step_21_due_date | step_21_complete | step_22_due_date | user_id
1  |      2016-03-08 | NULL             | NULL             | NULL             | 1
2  |      2016-03-08 | NULL             | NULL             | NULL             | 1
3  |      2016-03-08 | NULL             | NULL             | NULL             | 2
4  |      2016-01-03 | NULL             | NULL             | NULL             | 2
5  | NULL            | 2016-03-08       | NULL             | NULL             | 2
```

And second one which is the count of the date which is not null and `group by user_id`

```
step_1_complete | step_21_due_date | step_21_complete | step_22_due_date | user_id
2          |  0         |  0         |  0         | 1
2          |  1         |  0         |  0         | 2
```

I don't know it is possible or not using MySQL, any help or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: sure it is possible. You could write a cursor in a stored proc

Comment: performance would be awful

Comment: Have you considered using `CASE WHEN step22_due_date IS NOT NULL THEN step_22_due_date WHEN step_21_complete IS NOT NULL THEN .... ELSE .. END`  You can definitely write your logic with an expression like that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Comment: @Drew: i dont know about `cursor` but will search in google. what u thing should i do this in DB layer or Programming layer?

Comment: @OllieJones: thanks, let me try it.

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's a **column** - not a "coloum" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, of my question,

**For Data list**

```
SET @USER_DATE = '2016-03-08';

SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT `id`,
          `user_id`,
          `step_1_complete`,
          NULL AS `step_21_due_date`,
          NULL AS `step_21_complete`,
          NULL AS `step_22_due_date`
   FROM `pf_acc_status`
   WHERE `step_1_complete` IS NOT NULL
     AND `step_1_complete` <= @USER_DATE
     AND (`step_21_due_date` IS NULL
          OR step_21_due_date >= @USER_DATE)
   UNION ALL SELECT `id`,
                    `user_id`,
                    NULL AS `step_1_complete`,
                    `step_21_due_date`,
                    NULL AS `step_21_complete`,
                    NULL AS `step_22_due_date`
   FROM `pf_acc_status`
   WHERE `step_21_due_date` IS NOT NULL
     AND `step_21_due_date` <= @USER_DATE
     AND (`step_21_complete` IS NULL
          OR step_21_complete >= @USER_DATE)
   UNION ALL SELECT `id`,
                    `user_id`,
                    NULL AS `step_1_complete`,
                    NULL AS `step_21_due_date`,
                    `step_21_complete`,
                    NULL AS `step_22_due_date`
   FROM `pf_acc_status`
   WHERE `step_21_complete` IS NOT NULL
     AND `step_21_complete` <= @USER_DATE
     AND (`step_22_due_date` IS NULL
          OR step_22_due_date >= @USER_DATE)
   UNION ALL SELECT `id`,
                    `user_id`,
                    NULL AS `step_1_complete`,
                    NULL AS `step_21_due_date`,
                    NULL AS `step_21_complete`,
                    `step_22_due_date`
   FROM `pf_acc_status`
   WHERE `step_22_due_date` IS NOT NULL
     AND `step_22_due_date` <= @USER_DATE ) AS `a`
ORDER BY a.`id` ASC
```

**For `count` data**

```
SET @USER_DATE = '2016-03-08';

SELECT a.`user_id`,
       count(a.`step_1_complete`) AS step_1_complete,
       count(a.`step_21_due_date`) AS step_21_due_date,
       count(a.`step_21_complete`) AS step_21_complete,
       count(a.`step_22_due_date`) AS step_22_due_date
FROM
  (SELECT `id`,
          `user_id`,
          `step_1_complete`,
          NULL AS `step_21_due_date`,
          NULL AS `step_21_complete`,
          NULL AS `step_22_due_date`
   FROM `pf_acc_status`
   WHERE `step_1_complete` IS NOT NULL
     AND `step_1_complete` <= @USER_DATE
     AND (`step_21_due_date` IS NULL
          OR step_21_due_date >= @USER_DATE)
   UNION ALL SELECT `id`,
                    `user_id`,
                    NULL AS `step_1_complete`,
                    `step_21_due_date`,
                    NULL AS `step_21_complete`,
                    NULL AS `step_22_due_date`
   FROM `pf_acc_status`
   WHERE `step_21_due_date` IS NOT NULL
     AND `step_21_due_date` <= @USER_DATE
     AND (`step_21_complete` IS NULL
          OR step_21_complete >= @USER_DATE)
   UNION ALL SELECT `id`,
                    `user_id`,
                    NULL AS `step_1_complete`,
                    NULL AS `step_21_due_date`,
                    `step_21_complete`,
                    NULL AS `step_22_due_date`
   FROM `pf_acc_status`
   WHERE `step_21_complete` IS NOT NULL
     AND `step_21_complete` <= @USER_DATE
     AND (`step_22_due_date` IS NULL
          OR step_22_due_date >= @USER_DATE)
   UNION ALL SELECT `id`,
                    `user_id`,
                    NULL AS `step_1_complete`,
                    NULL AS `step_21_due_date`,
                    NULL AS `step_21_complete`,
                    `step_22_due_date`
   FROM `pf_acc_status`
   WHERE `step_22_due_date` IS NOT NULL
     AND `step_22_due_date` <= @USER_DATE ) AS `a`
GROUP BY a.`user_id`
ORDER BY a.`id` ASC
```